# Reaction between copper and silver(I) nitrate in aqueous medium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, reduction-potential

> What is the reaction between $\ce{Cu}$ and $\ce{AgNO3}$ taking place in aqueous medium?

The answer given was:

> "Only" oxidation of $\ce{Cu}.$

My concern is: how is only oxidation of $\ce{Cu}$ happening, as redox will occur in pair?

So either $\ce{Ag}$ will reduce, or $\ce{NO3-}$ will. But, since $\ce{Ag}$ has higher reduction potential, it won't. What will happen?

What does $\ce{NO3-}$ reduce into, if it does at all?

Comment: The context of other answers would help to understand, why the answer was formulated this way.

Comment: Why, according to the corresponding [SEPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)) the reaction $$\ce{Cu(s) + 2 AgNO3(aq) → Cu(NO3)2(aq) + 2 Ag(s)}$$ is plausible and in fact takes place (sometimes called a "snowy tree" reaction). However, you are correct, the given answer makes no sense.

Comment: @andselisk Sorry , I got confused with SEP of Ag and Cu, You are right , Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @andselisk Also does$\ce{ NO3-}$ , gets reduced or oxidised ?? What does it reduce or oxidise to??

Comment: Nothing happens to nitrate (N is already fully oxidized) and you should try quite hard to get it reduced under those conditions.

Comment: @user232243 No prob, keep in mind you can answer your own question (feel free to use my comment as a starting point, no need to cite me though) if you understand it now.

Comment: @EdV Sure, zinc is a much better reducing agent that copper. Nice addition to the question!